# Как обратиться к последнему элементу массива в ассемблере?

Tags: массивы, ассемблер, консоль, masm32

подскажите как обратиться к последнему элементу массива? Задание состояло в том, чтобы поменять максимальный четный элемент массива с последним. Есть код который делает обмен между макс.чет и макс.нечетным, а вот как исправить, чтобы менялось с последним не знаю

```
    .586 
.model flat, stdcall 
option casemap : none 

include \masm32\include\windows.inc 
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
include \masm32\include\user32.inc 
include \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc 
setlocale PROTO : Dword, :Dword  
; Підключення  файлів бібліотек 
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib 
includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib                      
.STACK 
.DATA 
ConsoleTitle  db "  Лабораторна  робота №5 ",0   ;  заголовок вікна  консолі 
Name_Title              db  30 dup(0) 
 ComSizeMas            db " Введіть розмір масиву ",13,10 
Len_ComSize equ $- ComSizeMas  ; різниця між адресами змінних є розмір        ;      попереднього поля    ComSizeMas 
ComElemMas  db " Введіть елементи масиву ",13,10 
Len_ComElem equ $- ComElemMas 
ComMasBefore db " Масив до обробки  ",13,10 
Len_MasBefore equ $- ComMasBefore 
ComMasAfter   db  " Масив  після обробки ",13,10 
Len_MasAfter  equ $- ComMasAfter 
format_size_buf db "%d",0 
format_print_buf  db    " %5d ",0   
koder             db     "Russian",0  
print_buf_b  db "Buf [  ",0 
print_buf_e  db "]=",0 
print_13_10       db    13,10,0 
print_13    db    13,0 
pos_max dd -1 
max_nechet dd 0 
a dd 0 
b dd 0 
.DATA? 
Buf  dd 100 dup(?)   ;  максимальний обсяг масиву 
Size_buf dd ? ;  фактичний розмір масиву 
h_input dd ? ;   дескриптор пристрою вводу 
h_output dd ? ;   дескриптор пристрою виводу 
nWrite  dd ? ; змінна для функції WriteConsole 
number_element dd ?     ;  поточний номер елементу вводу 
element_buf dd ? ;   змінна для вводу елементу масиву 
.CODE 
main   proc  
call AllocConsole     ;   створення власної консолі 
;   перетворення символів в формат Oem  для виводу заголовку 
invoke   CharToOemA, addr ConsoleTitle, addr Name_Title   
invoke   SetConsoleTitle,   addr Name_Title       ;  вивід заголовку 
invoke  GetStdHandle,   STD_INPUT_HANDLE  
mov h_input, eax  ; отримали дескриптор пристою вводу 
invoke  GetStdHandle,   STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE          
mov h_output, eax                 ;  отримали дескриптор пристрою виводу 
invoke SetConsoleOutputCP,1251    ;  підтримка кириліці 
invoke SetConsoleCP,1251     

call input_mas      ;  Ввід початкових даних 
call print_rezult   ;   Вивід результатів  
call work_mas       ;   Обробка масиву 
call print_rezult_obr   ;   Вивід результатів  

invoke Sleep,100000000  ;  Затримка зображення на екрані    

call FreeConsole 
invoke ExitProcess, 0   ;  Завершення програми 

main endp  ;--------------------------------------------------------  
input_mas   proc ;      Запрошення для вводу розміру масиву 
invoke  WriteConsole, h_output, ADDR ComSizeMas, Len_ComSize, ADDR nWrite, 0  

invoke      crt_scanf,  ADDR format_size_buf, ADDR Size_buf     ; форматний ввід 
;   !!!!   Виконати перевірку        1<= Size_buf<=100  у разі помилки – повторити ввід 
mov number_element, 0   
m_input_buf: 
invoke WriteConsole, h_output, ADDR print_buf_b, 7, ADDR nWrite, 0     ; Вивід  buf [ 
invoke      crt_printf, ADDR format_size_buf , number_element   ;  вивід  № елементу 
invoke WriteConsole, h_output, ADDR print_buf_e, 2, ADDR nWrite, 0   ; Вивід  ]=  
invoke      crt_scanf, ADDR format_size_buf, ADDR  element_buf   ; Ввід елем.масив. 
or eax,eax     
jnz m_1     ; немає помилки 
;  помилка вводу  - очистка буферу вводу 
m_2: 
invoke crt_getchar 
cmp eax,10 ;  доки не enter 
jne m_2 
invoke      crt_printf,   ADDR print_13 
jmp m_input_buf 
m_1: 
mov eax,   element_buf          
mov esi,   number_element      
shl esi,2             
mov Buf [esi],  eax          
inc number_element      
mov  edx,   number_element 
cmp edx,   Size_buf              
jnz  m_input_buf      ;    цикл без використання команди   LOOP  

     ret 
input_mas   endp 
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
print_rezult  proc      ;  Вивід результатів 
invoke WriteConsole, h_output, ADDR ComMasBefore, Len_MasBefore, ADDR nWrite, 0  
mov number_element,0                
m1:   mov ecx,5  ;      вивід по 5 елементі в рядок 
m2:    push ecx 
mov eax,number_element               
shl eax,2             
mov esi,eax         
invoke      crt_printf,   ADDR format_print_buf   ,  Buf[esi]        
pop ecx 
inc number_element  
mov  edx, number_element 
cmp edx, Size_buf                
jz m_ret        ;       всі елементи виведені 
dec ecx 
jnz m2 
invoke      crt_printf,   ADDR print_13_10 ;  перехід на новий рядок      
jmp m1 
m_ret:  ret  
print_rezult    endp ;------------------------------------------------------ 


work_mas  proc       ;   Основний алгоритм, реалізується декількома процедурами  
lea ebx, Buf 
mov ecx, Size_buf 

call nechet_max 
CMP edi,0 
JE   a9 
XOR EDI,EDI 
call chet_max 
CMP edi,0 
JE   a9 
XOR EDI,EDI 

call nechet  ; виклик процедури  пошуку макс. значення         
mov esi,  edi; ; номер максимального елементу         
mov a,esi        
 mov  eax, Buf[esi*4]         
mov max_nechet, eax 
mov pos_max,-1 

call chet 
mov esi,  edi 
mov b,esi ; номер максимального елементу 
mov  edx, Buf[esi*4] 
mov eax,max_nechet 
mov esi,a 
mov Buf[esi*4],edx 
mov esi,b 
mov Buf[esi*4],eax 
mov ecx,Size_buf 
a9: ret 
work_mas  endp 

nechet_max proc 
xor esi,esi 
xor edi, edi 
mov ecx,Size_buf 
M5:mov edx, [ebx+esi*4] ;  в edx  перший елемент масиву         
test edx,1         
jz D7          
INC EDI       
D7: inc esi          
loop M5 
ret 
nechet_max endp 


chet_max proc 
xor esi,esi 
xor edi, edi 
mov ecx,Size_buf 
M5:mov edx, [ebx+esi*4] ;  в edx  перший елемент масиву        
test edx,1         
jnz D7         
INC EDI       
D7: inc esi          
loop M5 
ret 
chet_max endp 

nechet proc 
xor esi,esi 
xor edi, edi 
mov ecx,Size_buf             
M5:mov edx, [ebx+esi*4] ;  в edx  перший елемент масиву         
test edx,1 
   jz D7         
mov eax, edx          
jmp D2       
D7: inc esi          
loop M5 
 D2:     xor esi,esi  
mov ecx,Size_buf  
@1:  mov edx, [ebx+esi*4]     
test edx,1     
jz a1 ; если четное     
BT edx, 31     
jnc M1     
neg edx   
M1:  cmp edx, eax      
jl     a1 ;   перехід, якщо елемент масиву менший або дорі максимальному        
mov  eax, edx      
mov  edi, esi      
a1:  inc esi   ;  наступний елемент масиву      
loop @1 
N1: ret 
nechet endp 

chet proc 
xor esi,esi 
xor edi,edi 
mov ecx,Size_buf                    
 M4:mov edx, [ebx+esi*4] ;  в edx  перший елемент масиву        
 test edx,1         
jnz D3         
mov eax, edx  
jmp D1       
D3: inc esi         
Loop M4      
jmp N2 
D1: xor esi,esi       
mov ecx,Size_buf 
@2:  mov edx, [ebx+esi*4]     
test edx,1     
jnz a1 ; если не четное     
BT edx, 31     
jnc M2     
neg edx    
M2: cmp edx, eax     
jle     a1 ;   перехід, якщо елемент масиву менший або дорі максимальному        
mov  eax, edx      
mov  edi, esi     
a1:  inc esi  ;  наступний елемент масиву   
loop @2 
N2: ret 
chet endp 
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
print_rezult_obr  proc      ;  Вивід результатів  
invoke      crt_printf,   ADDR print_13_10 ;  
invoke WriteConsole, h_output, ADDR ComMasAfter, Len_MasAfter, ADDR nWrite, 0      
mov number_element,0                
m1:   mov ecx,5  ;      вивід по 5 елементі в рядок 
m2:    push ecx 
    mov eax,number_element                   
shl eax,2                  
mov esi,eax             
invoke      crt_printf,   ADDR format_print_buf   ,  Buf[esi]            
pop ecx     
inc number_element      
mov  edx, number_element     
cmp edx, Size_buf                    
jz m_ret        ;       всі елементи виведені      
dec ecx      
jnz m2      
invoke      crt_printf,   ADDR print_13_10 ;  перехід на новий рядок      
jmp m1 
m_ret:  ret  
print_rezult_obr    endp 
;---------------------------------------------------------------- 
end main
```

Answer (score 0):

Если кому-то будет надо:

```
.586 
.model flat, stdcall 
option casemap : none 

include \masm32\include\windows.inc 
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
include \masm32\include\user32.inc 
include \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc 
setlocale PROTO : Dword, :Dword  
; Підключення  файлів бібліотек 
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib 
includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib                      
.STACK 
.DATA 
ConsoleTitle  db "  Лабораторна  робота №5 ",0   ;  заголовок вікна  консолі 
Name_Title              db  30 dup(0) 
 ComSizeMas            db " Введіть розмір масиву ",13,10 
Len_ComSize equ $- ComSizeMas  ; різниця між адресами змінних є розмір        ;      попереднього поля    ComSizeMas 
ComElemMas  db " Введіть елементи масиву ",13,10 
Len_ComElem equ $- ComElemMas 
ComMasBefore db " Масив до обробки  ",13,10 
Len_MasBefore equ $- ComMasBefore 
ComMasAfter   db  " Масив  після обробки ",13,10 
Len_MasAfter  equ $- ComMasAfter 
format_size_buf db "%d",0 
format_print_buf  db    " %5d ",0   
koder             db     "Russian",0  
print_buf_b  db "Buf [  ",0 
print_buf_e  db "]=",0 
print_13_10       db    13,10,0 
print_13    db    13,0 
pos_max dd -1 
max_nechet dd 0 
a dd 0 
b dd 0 
.DATA? 
Buf  dd 100 dup(?)   ;  максимальний обсяг масиву 
Size_buf dd ? ;  фактичний розмір масиву 
h_input dd ? ;   дескриптор пристрою вводу 
h_output dd ? ;   дескриптор пристрою виводу 
nWrite  dd ? ; змінна для функції WriteConsole 
number_element dd ?     ;  поточний номер елементу вводу 
element_buf dd ? ;   змінна для вводу елементу масиву 
.CODE 
main   proc  
call AllocConsole     ;   створення власної консолі 
;   перетворення символів в формат Oem  для виводу заголовку 
invoke   CharToOemA, addr ConsoleTitle, addr Name_Title   
invoke   SetConsoleTitle,   addr Name_Title       ;  вивід заголовку 
invoke  GetStdHandle,   STD_INPUT_HANDLE  
mov h_input, eax  ; отримали дескриптор пристою вводу 
invoke  GetStdHandle,   STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE          
mov h_output, eax                 ;  отримали дескриптор пристрою виводу 
invoke SetConsoleOutputCP,1251    ;  підтримка кириліці 
invoke SetConsoleCP,1251     

call input_mas      ;  Ввід початкових даних 
call print_rezult   ;   Вивід результатів  
call work_mas       ;   Обробка масиву 
call print_rezult_obr   ;   Вивід результатів  

invoke Sleep,100000000  ;  Затримка зображення на екрані    

call FreeConsole 
invoke ExitProcess, 0   ;  Завершення програми 

main endp  ;--------------------------------------------------------  
input_mas   proc ;      Запрошення для вводу розміру масиву 
    ENTER_AGAIN:

    invoke  WriteConsole, h_output, ADDR ComSizeMas, Len_ComSize, ADDR nWrite, 0  
    invoke      crt_scanf,  ADDR format_size_buf, ADDR Size_buf     ; форматний ввід

    cmp Size_buf, 0 ; проверка на ввод размера меньше нуля
    jle ENTER_AGAIN ; если размер меньше нуля, переход на метку ENTER_AGAIN
    cmp Size_buf, 100 ; проверка на ввод больше 100
    jg ENTER_AGAIN ; если размер больше 100, переход на метку ENTER_AGAIN

    ;   !!!!   Виконати перевірку        1<= Size_buf<=100  у разі помилки – повторити ввід 
    mov number_element, 0   
    m_input_buf: 
    invoke WriteConsole, h_output, ADDR print_buf_b, 7, ADDR nWrite, 0     ; Вивід  buf [ 
    invoke      crt_printf, ADDR format_size_buf , number_element   ;  вивід  № елементу 
    invoke WriteConsole, h_output, ADDR print_buf_e, 2, ADDR nWrite, 0   ; Вивід  ]=  
    invoke      crt_scanf, ADDR format_size_buf, ADDR  element_buf   ; Ввід елем.масив. 
    or eax,eax     
    jnz m_1     ; немає помилки 
    ;  помилка вводу  - очистка буферу вводу 
    m_2: 
    invoke crt_getchar 
    cmp eax,10 ;  доки не enter 
    jne m_2 
    invoke      crt_printf,   ADDR print_13 
    jmp m_input_buf 
    m_1: 
    mov eax,   element_buf          
    mov esi,   number_element      
    shl esi,2             
    mov Buf [esi],  eax          
    inc number_element      
    mov  edx,   number_element 
    cmp edx,   Size_buf              
    jnz  m_input_buf      ;    цикл без використання команди   LOOP  

         ret 
input_mas   endp 
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
print_rezult  proc      ;  Вивід результатів 
    invoke WriteConsole, h_output, ADDR ComMasBefore, Len_MasBefore, ADDR nWrite, 0  
    mov number_element,0                
    m1:   mov ecx,5  ;      вивід по 5 елементі в рядок 
    m2:    push ecx 
    mov eax,number_element               
    shl eax,2             
    mov esi,eax         
    invoke      crt_printf,   ADDR format_print_buf   ,  Buf[esi]        
    pop ecx 
    inc number_element  
    mov  edx, number_element 
    cmp edx, Size_buf                
    jz m_ret        ;       всі елементи виведені 
    dec ecx 
    jnz m2 
    invoke      crt_printf,   ADDR print_13_10 ;  перехід на новий рядок      
    jmp m1 
    m_ret:  ret  
print_rezult    endp ;------------------------------------------------------ 


work_mas  proc       ;   Основний алгоритм, реалізується декількома процедурами  
    lea ebx, Buf 
    mov ecx, Size_buf 

    call nechet_max 
    CMP edi,0 
    JE   a9 
    XOR EDI,EDI 
    call chet_max 
    CMP edi,0 
    JE   a9 
    XOR EDI,EDI 

    call chet 
    mov esi,  eax 
    mov b,esi ; номер максимального елементу 
    mov  edx, Buf[esi*4] 
    ;mov eax,max_nechet 
    ;mov esi,a 
    mov ECX, Size_buf
    dec ECX
    ; замена последнего элемента макс. чётным
    mov EAX, Buf[ECX*4]
    mov Buf[ECX*4],edx
    ;mov esi,b 
    ; замена макс. чётного элемента последним
    mov Buf[esi*4],eax 
    inc ECX
    a9: ret 
work_mas  endp 

nechet_max proc 
    xor esi,esi 
    xor edi, edi 
    mov ecx,Size_buf 
    M5:mov edx, [ebx+esi*4] ;  в edx  перший елемент масиву         
    test edx,1         
    jz D7          
    INC EDI       
    D7: inc esi          
    loop M5 
    ret 
nechet_max endp 


chet_max proc 
    xor esi,esi 
    xor edi, edi 
    mov ecx,Size_buf 
    M5:mov edx, [ebx+esi*4] ;  в edx  перший елемент масиву        
    test edx,1         
    jnz D7         
    INC EDI       
    D7: inc esi          
    loop M5 
    ret 
chet_max endp 

chet proc 
    xor esi,esi 
    xor edi,edi 

    mov ecx,Size_buf                    
    M4:
        mov edx, [ebx+esi*4] ;  в edx  перший елемент масиву        
        test edx,1         
        jnz D3         
        ;mov eax, edx
        mov eax, esi
        jmp D1       
        D3: inc esi         
    Loop M4      

    jmp N2 

    D1: xor esi,esi       
    mov ecx,Size_buf 

    @2:  
        mov edx, [ebx+esi*4]     
        test edx,1     
        jnz a1 ; если не четное
        cmp edx, [ebx+eax*4]
        jle a1
            mov eax, esi   
        a1:  
        inc esi  ;  наступний елемент масиву   
    loop @2 

    N2: ret 
chet endp 
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
print_rezult_obr  proc      ;  Вивід результатів  
    invoke      crt_printf,   ADDR print_13_10 ;  
    invoke WriteConsole, h_output, ADDR ComMasAfter, Len_MasAfter, ADDR nWrite, 0      
    mov number_element,0                
    m1:   mov ecx,5  ;      вивід по 5 елементі в рядок 
    m2:    push ecx 
        mov eax,number_element                   
    shl eax,2                  
    mov esi,eax             
    invoke      crt_printf,   ADDR format_print_buf   ,  Buf[esi]            
    pop ecx     
    inc number_element      
    mov  edx, number_element     
    cmp edx, Size_buf                    
    jz m_ret        ;       всі елементи виведені      
    dec ecx      
    jnz m2      
    invoke      crt_printf,   ADDR print_13_10 ;  перехід на новий рядок      
    jmp m1 
    m_ret:  ret  
print_rezult_obr    endp 
;---------------------------------------------------------------- 
end main
```